# Lua: Problems with binding my games entity system

Tags: c++, lua

The game I am making currently has a simple entity system. I have the CEntity class (not using inheritance, component based) and the entity manager.

CEntity is bound to Lua with a metatable, and when you create a new entity from within Lua, a new entity is created in C++ within the allocated userdata.

So that would be all fine however I have come across one huge problem:

- How do I implement something like ents.GetByID()?

ents.GetByID() should return a reference to the entity with ID x. What I currently do: Create a new userdata, fill with memcpy() of existing entity x.

This, however clearly doesn't work: First, it messes up the entity manager, and second: If I change the "reference" entity, the actual entity remains the same - I actually have two separate entities.

- How do I push a reference to an existing userdatum on the stack?

Comment: OP requested to delete question, and cleared content. @Cats: Why?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you have to do is bind a specific key (say, ID) inside the Lua registry to the userdata. Also, memcpy = bad, mmkay?

If you wrote a simple C function that returns the Lua registry table, it would be pretty trivial and easier to write this code in the Lua side.

```
make_entity = function(ID, ...)
    local entity = CreateEntity(...);
    get_registry().EntityIDMap[ID] = entity;
    return entity;
end

get_entity = function(ID) 
    return get_registry().EntityIDMap[ID];
end
```